# Cannot navigate to child routes using router.navigate method or routerlink :: Error : Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'child2'

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

[image: Click to view Page Wireframe]

Here is my routes constant

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: 'child1'
      },
      {
        path: 'child1',
        component: Child1Component
      },
      {
        path: 'child2',
        component: Child2Component
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

```js
RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
```

added this line in imports of module.

inside of MenuComponent, I am trying to navigate to respective child component on click of any of the menus(child1 or child2) using this line

```js
this.router.navigate(['/dashboard/child1']); //or tried with this.router.navigate(['child1']);
```

router-outlet is in DashboardComponent

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is probably happening because of the first match strategy of Angular. When you try to hit any URL, the wildcard is the first to be encountered and it is true for all. Put it at the end and it will work.

> The order of the routes in the configuration matters and this is by design. The router uses a first-match wins strategy when matching routes, so more specific routes should be placed above less specific routes. In the configuration above, routes with a static path are listed first, followed by an empty path route, that matches the default route. The wildcard route comes last because it matches every URL and should be selected only if no other routes are matched first. [Angular Router](https://angular.io/guide/router)

```
{
path: 'dashboard',
component: DashboardComponent,
children: [
  {
    path: 'child1',
    component: Child1Component
  },
  {
    path: 'child2',
    component: Child2Component
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'child1'
  }
]
```

}

Comment: @Faraz Oh Got it!! Thanks. I have a question now, it is working fine if I use whole path 'dashboard/child1' in navigation from MenuComponent but not with 'child1'. Why isn't it taking the relative path?

Comment: @suraj13k thats because  path 'child1' is a child path. And it can only be reached through parent. when you specify '/child1'  it searches at parent level(level 1) only, there it does not find any path relating to 'child1'. but when you specify '/dashboard/child1', it searches for 'dashboard' and when it finds dashboard it searches in its children for the matching path.

Comment: @Faraz Yes but here MenuComponent(used as a directive) is part of dashboardComponent. It should work with 'child1' according to me.

Answer (score 0):

The parent component will be DashboardComponent because it matches the routing.

In order to have sub-routing in Angular, you have to place

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

inside your DashboardComponent, so that the router will know where to place Child1Component.

Comment: router-outlet is in DashboardComponent. I have mentioned it in my question

Comment: can you share the HTML template of DashboardComponent?